# How to keep column names when using as.data.frame

Tags: r

I'm trying to convert list to data frame and it changes columns names.
List looks like

```
ids

Name1      Name2
"CatValue" 6
```

when I run     `as.data.frame(ids, optional = FALSE)`
it changes to:

```
ids.Name1      ids.Name2
"CatValue"     6
```

But it should stay the same.

How to avoid this? I thought that optional argument was going to help, but as you can see it didn't happen.

EDIT:
I see that it wasn't clear enough so I will try to show you big picture.

I have written a **scraper** which assigns data frame to value like id0001, id0002 etc. I want to use these data frames in for-loop so I use code like this to get to them
`table<-mget(ids0001)`
and `typeof(table)` is list (no idea why). I need to transform this to data.frame (to make my loop work).

The problem is, what's assigned to `table` should be table not list (and it was before I use `mget()`.

both, my first data.frame, list and data.frame after using mget() look like this, the problem is  as.data.frame adds `ids0001.` to column name.

```
 GAME_ID E VENTNUM EVENTMSGTYP EVENTMSGACTIONTYPE   PERIOD   WCTIMESTRING
1 0021500001 0       12            0                    1       8:12 PM
2 0021500001 1       10            0                    1       8:12 PM
3 0021500001 2        2           42                    1       8:13 PM
4 0021500001 3        4            0                    1       8:13 PM
5 0021500001 4        5           45                    1       8:13 PM
6 0021500001 5        1           80                    1       8:13 PM
```

EDIT 2:
Now I can see mget() creates a list like below. it was too long and I missed that

```
 id0001$
 GAME_ID E VENTNUM EVENTMSGTYP EVENTMSGACTIONTYPE   PERIOD   WCTIMESTRING
1 0021500001 0       12            0                    1       8:12 PM
2 0021500001 1       10            0                    1       8:12 PM
3 0021500001 2        2           42                    1       8:13 PM
4 0021500001 3        4            0                    1       8:13 PM
5 0021500001 4        5           45                    1       8:13 PM
6 0021500001 5        1           80                    1       8:13 PM
```

Comment: try by setting the names of list to NULL or use `[[`

Comment: you should give more info. do you only have one data frame in a named list? then `ids[[1]]` should work. if you have multiple data frames in the list, what you are doing is going to bind them together but maybe you want them stacked

Comment: actually your solutions work. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can share how you generated the list it will be helpful. I tried to replicate your list ( or rather nearly). To avoid the default deparsed argument naming, you can specify a name `value = ids$ids`.

```
ids = list(ids = c(Name1 = "CatValue", Name2 = 6))
b <- data.frame(value = ids$ids)
t(b)
```

Output

```
      Name1      Name2
value "CatValue" "6"
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following:

```
> listSample <- list(Name1 = "catValue", Name2 = 6)
> listSample
$Name1
[1] "catValue"

$Name2
[1] 6

> listAsDF <- as.data.frame(listSample)
> listAsDF
Name1 Name2
1 catValue     6
```

Without seeing how you constructed your list, I'm not sure why you got something different.  If I'd not created the list the way I did and just changed to a DF, R would have added a prefix (i.e. "X") to "catValue" and 6 so my column names would be X.catValue and X6.

Comment: @rawr I've added some additional information. Sorry for not being clear